# Disable fields validation for entire form

Tags: django, forms, validation

For debug purposes I need to disable fields validation for entire form, so it will be always valid.

What I've tried:

- overriding form `clean()` and `full_clean()` methods, but seems like my
  view's statement `return render_to_response()` doesn’t invoke such methods, and I can't call any form method directly from view either (idk why)
- set all fields `required=False`, but I don't know why it wont work on particular field (maybe it need's for db to be resynced?..) either I don't know how to set it to all fields in bulk
- cleaning `form._errors` dict, like that: `self._errors = ErrorDict()`, but I don't know where to write it.

view:

```
def step_1(request, vac_id):
    b_fl = False
    try:
        if request.META['HTTP_REFERER'].find(u'step-2') == -1:
            b_fl = True
    except:
        b_fl = True
    if b_fl:
        for key in res_keys:
            for skey in res_keys[key]:
                if skey in request.session:
                    del request.session[skey]
    if vac_id:
        vacancy = Vacancy.objects.get(pk=vac_id)
    else:
        vacancy = None
    res_list = {}
    for i in res_keys[1]:
        if i in request.session:
            res_list[i] = request.session[i]
        else:
            res_list[i] = None
    if 'vac_id' in request.session:
        vac_id = int(request.session['vac_id'])
        if vac_id:
            pr_vacancy = Vacancy.objects.get(pk=vac_id)
        else:
            pr_vacancy = None
    else:
        pr_vacancy = None
    if 'vac_text' in request.session:
        vac_text = request.session['vac_text']
    else:
        vac_text = None

    return render_to_response('step_1.html',
                              {'vacancy': vacancy,
                               'res_list': res_list,
                               'pr_vacancy': pr_vacancy,
                               'vac_text': vac_text
                              },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

form:

```
class FeedbackForm(forms.Form):
    vacancy = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    vacancy_text = forms.CharField(required=False)
    salary_min = forms.CharField()
    salary_opt = forms.CharField()
    <..>
    <lots of fields here>
    <..>
    recommendations = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False)
    dis_rec_reas = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
    how_about_us = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

Comment: The `clean()` method is for a _form_, not a view. What is the actual problem you are debugging? There might be a better solution than this - which is very hackish.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I know, I overrided it in form, not in view. My actual problem really is to quickly disable validation for entire form. :)

Comment: I think its better if you post the code that is giving you problems; it seems your issue is in the view: _"seems like my view's statement return render_to_response() doesn’t invoke such methods, and I can't call any form method directly from view either"_.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid fxd, look plz

Comment: I don't see any place in your view that you even use the form. Maybe you posted the wrong view method?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I checked it out - form is never imported o_0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, seems like all abovementioned solutions doesn’t work because that form isn't in use at all :D All the job done between view-n-template.

idk if I should delete the question now.. o_0